# How to add grant type into access token in IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4

I need to know the client's grant type (or OAuth Flow type) in my API protected by IdentitySrever4, but not sure how to do that. I am assuming that I need to add the grant type to the access token. Can someone help me by pointing me to instructions/documentations or sample code?

**UPDATE**

Under standard IdentityServer4 EF model, my SQL Server data store has a ClientGrantTypes table and a ClientClaims table (see screenshot below). I am assuming that I need to create a ClientClaims record that ties into ClientGrantTypes. If it is SQL, you can just join the tables on ClientID, but how do you implement it here to get the Grant Type into access token?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to find the answer if you explained the purpose for the requirement. 
From my experience one common task is to distinguish `authorization_code` and `client_credentials` flow use for the same client, but that's easy: the second one does not contain user information (`sub` and `sid` claims).

Also don't forget about restricted auth flow combinations in Identityserver (for instance you can't allow both `implicit` and `authorization_code` flow for the same client), so one client is usually bound to the only user interactive flow.

Finally, the auth flow is generally not about API. It's only about interaction among IdP and Client. API usually use scopes as general information about clients, so... when you have two clients -- one with `implicit` grant and the other with `authorization_code`, you can distinguish which one is in use by setting different scopes.

Isn't that enough?

A [check for a particular grant type](https://github.com/dfrunet/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/9bb00961aa22c2d105b2259541acc065415b7d9b/Extensions/ExtendedClaimsService.cs#L159) could be performed in Identityserver the following way:

```cs
public class ExtendedClaimsService : DefaultClaimsService{
    public override async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetAccessTokenClaimsAsync(
            ClaimsPrincipal subject,
            ResourceValidationResult resourceResult,
            ValidatedRequest request)
    {
        var outputClaims = (await base.GetAccessTokenClaimsAsync(subject, resourceResult, request)).ToList();

        //if (request.Secret.Type == "NoSecret") //this is more or less the same
        if ((request as ValidatedTokenRequest)?.GrantType != "client_credentials")
            {
                //filter out server-side-only scopes here
                //or add any custom claim you like
            }

        return outputClaims;
    }
}
```

Registration: `services.AddTransient<IClaimsService, ExtendedClaimsService>();` after `services.AddIdentityServer()` in your `Startup`

Comment: Yes, you are right in that what I am trying to do here is to distinguish between authorization_code and client_credentials flows. And yes, what I am doing now is by testing the existence of user id. If that's the standard way, or at least a reliable way to do it, then I guess I am OK. I have been considering that as a workaround, not a solution. That's why I was looking for ways to add grant type as a claim.

Comment: that is indeed reliable as the claimsset is signed by the IdP, so a user can't just remove the sub claim to gain more access. what I am thinking about right now is to perform such check on identityserver side to make requesting some ".service" scopes absolutely impossible without service creds (even the scope is allowed for the client).

Comment: one limitation can occur when you use custom "delegation" flow -- client creds with user info inside. if you do use delegation, you definitely need a separate "trusted-client" claim, but most likely you do not : )

Comment: @Alexu, just updated the answer with a piece of code. Don't hesitate to vote up : )

Comment: I did. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have different client definitions for the different flows and then use a [ClientClaim](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/claims/#client-claims) to indicate what type of client it is:

To set the client claims in the client definition just set it like:

```
ClientClaimsPrefix="",

AlwaysSendClientClaims=true,

Claims = new List<ClientClaim>()
{
    new ClientClaim("role","admin"),
    new ClientClaim("name","joe"),
    new ClientClaim("admin","yes"),
    new ClientClaim("employmentid","employee"),
    new ClientClaim("employeetype","yes"),
    new ClientClaim("creditlimit","100000")
}
```

Comment: That's what I am thinking - can I create a ClientClaim based on the ClientGrantType of the client? If so, how?

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: That I know. But I need to link ClientClaim with ClientGrantType. See update from my post. Thanks.