# What scope does "idp" belong to in IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4, idp

My MVC client's access token contains an "idp" claim that my simple server-to-server client's token doesn't. I don't explicitly request idp on either clients, so where is this claim coming from? I thought it was part of "openid", and since it is available by default to MVC client, you don't need to request it, but I couldn't find any documentation/specification that confirms it. By the way, I am unable to add the openid scope to my serer-to-server client, as I am getting "invalid scope" error when I do that. What I am trying to do here is to get the "idp" claim into the token for my server-to-server client as well, but not sure if that's possible. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Hi @Alexu, am I right understand that you want to include the idp claim into access_token, not into the id_token? Which grant_type do you use for issue tokens?

Comment: That's right. I use both authentication-code flow (in MVC) and client-credential flow (in server-to-server client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do server to server communication using the **client-credentials flow**, there is no user involved and hence the **openid** scope has no purpose. As its core purpose is to ask for the subject claim (the user Id).

The **idp** claim is not part of any scope and is usually added by IdentityServer.

Why do you neeed the **idp** claim? Your API and client both trusts the shared IdentiyServer.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the idp for me. Not sure why IdentityServer doc doesn't have (or I couldn't find) any explanation for this. I just want to have that info on the API side for auditing purpose, nothing really critical, but I still want to understand. I guess I could use iss for that, as d_f suggested below.

Comment: @Alexu if your purpose is audit, **use** `idp` when exists (sometimes there will be just _local_). `iss` is who issued the token, while `idp` is who authenticated the user. That is the difference, and yes, it is not documented by either OpenId Foundation or Identityserver afaik

Answer (score 1):

`idp` claim in Identityserver stands for external identity provider (such as Google). That's why it does not have any sense when you request a token from your local IdP with "client_credentials" flow. If you are interested in the info about the token's issuer, just use `iss` claim instead. If you are sure you need the `idp` (or any other custom) claim in each and every token, you can involve a custom ClaimsService as I explained in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70432778/1426685).

Comment: sure. guess, I thought about "client credentials for the service" while was typing. thanks for finding the typo. in the referred answer it was correct.